# PHP return from function and loop again

Tags: php

I have a function, and depending on some values, it needs to get executed once more with different values. Here is an example:

```
function loop_again($num) {

    if (isset($num)) {

        if ($num == 1) {

          loop_again(2);

        }

        return $num.'<br />';

    }

}

echo loop_again(1);
```

My desired result is:

```
1
2
```

But I am only getting `1`.

How can I re-run the function and return both results in order?

Comment: @SandeepBansal It will not always be the next integer. It may be a completely different number.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return of the 2nd call

Comment: You may be looking for `recursion`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second loop is disappearing into the ether because you are not doing anything with the return value.  You want to either change your `return` to an echo or append the recursion to the string that you are returning.

```
function loop_again($num) {
    $number_string = '';
    if (isset($num)) {
        $number_string .= $num.'<br />';
        if ($num == 1) {

          $number_string .= loop_again(2);

        }

        return $number_string;

    }

}

echo loop_again(1);
```

Comment: Technical this is not `recursion` as there is no real end condition though

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually capture and retain the return value from the recursive call inside the function:

```
function loop_again($num) {

    if (isset($num)) {

        if ($num == 1) {

          $num = $num.'<br/>'.loop_again(2); //changed here

        }

        return $num.'<br />';

    }

}

echo loop_again(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Overall this seems like a really strange way to code the function.  A possibly better approach is to build an array of all data in the same function and return it.

Otherwise, if you must use recursion pass the data that is defined into the function.

```
function loop_again($level=1,$data=array()) {
    // append data to $data, and pass the args $level and $data into each recursive call

}
```